# Does it exist a solution to the system of differential equations: $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ and $xu_x-yu_y=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am solving a problem and have derived the following system of equations :

$$(1) \,\,\,\quad\quad u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$$
$$(2) \quad \quad xu_x-yu_y=0.$$

Does it exist an analytical function $u(x,y)$ that satisfies this system? I recognize (1) being **Laplace eq.** and I have seen solutions to (2) in this forum, but it is somewhat unclear how (1) and (2) would be connected. Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: How much do you know about partial differential equations? Why are you interested in this particular question?  
One can easily write a general solution to the first order equation: $u\left(x,y\right) = g\left(xy\right)$, and then verify that the only way this satisfies Laplace's equation is if $g\left(s\right)$ is an order 1 polynomial. So, the general solution to the system is
$$ u\left(x,y\right) = A+Bxy. $$

Comment: The second equation gives $$u(x,y)=f(xy)$$

Comment: I am solving the problem of finding all harmonic functions $u$ that $(x^2-y^2)u(x,y)$ also being harmonic, where I derived the system of eq. (1) and (2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the second equation, we have:
$$\frac {dx}{x}=\frac {dy}{-y}=\frac {du}{0}$$
$$du=0 \implies u=c_1$$
$$ \ln x = - \ln y +c_2 \implies c_2=xy$$
$$f(c_2)=c_1 \implies u(x,y)=f(xy)$$
Then from first equation:
$$\frac {\partial^2 f(xy)}{\partial_{xx}}+\frac {\partial^2 f(x,y)}{\partial_{yy}}=0$$
$$\frac {\partial^2 f(xy)}{\partial_{(xy)(xy)}}(x^2+y^2)=0$$
$$\frac {\partial^2 f(xy)}{\partial_{(xy)(xy)}}=0$$
$$\frac {\partial f(xy)}{\partial_{(xy)}}=A$$
$$f(xy)=A(xy)+B$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=A(xy)+B}$$
Is this correct @YMA ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain the first row of your solution, specifically $du/0$?

Comment: Thats the method of cvaracterisitic that is used for first order Partial Equation @OSCAR since on the left side of the equation you have zero

Comment: okey, I found more theory regarding this subject. That $du/0$ (although it is correct) looks very suspicious though for me as unfamiliar with the topic.

Comment: it means that $du=0$ it's abuse of notation @oscar